# Connect Four game

Tags: arrays, ruby

In my Ruby class, I'm building a Connect Four game that my professor will run in command prompt.

It has to be done with a double array and `while` loops, and no `break`/`exit`/`abort`, `loop do`, classes, instance, or global variables.

My grid array is made up of 64 `'.'` placeholders in a nested array. I am trying to start at the bottom row of my 8x8 grid, and drop in a player's piece: `'X'` or `'0'`.

I'm not sure how to move upward from row 8/index 7 to row 7/index 6 if the bottom row of a column has already been taken. Do I use `if` or `case` statements? Do I decrement the row? I have tried putting in `if`/`elsif`, but I got nowhere.

```
def print_playing_grid (playing_board)
  puts "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
  playing_board.each do |row|
    puts row.join(" ")
  end
end

print_playing_grid(grid_array)

# this 'win'/while is only here for testing so the board will repeat on screen
win = false
while win == false
  puts
  puts "Please select a column to make your move (Player X):"
  user_choice = gets.to_i
  row = 7
  column = user_choice - 1
  while row < grid_array.size
    grid_array[row][column] = 'X'
    row += 1
  end
  puts
  print_playing_grid(grid_array)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's only two conditions (cell is occupied or not) I'd be more likely to use an `if` rather than a `case`... I would use `case` for multiple tests as it can be a little cleaner than `if` and `elsif`.

```
player_token = 'X'
row = grid_array.size - 1
column = user_choice - 1
while (grid_array.size - row) <= grid_array.size
  if grid_array[row][column] == '.'
    grid_array[row][column] = player_token
    row = -1 # (to exit the while loop)
  else
    row -= 1
  end
end
```

for an example of where I'd consider using a case...

```
player_token = 'X'
row = grid_array.size - 1
column = user_choice - 1
dropping_a_token = true
while dropping_a_token
  case 
  when row < 0
    dropping_a_token = false
  when grid_array[row][column] == '.'
    grid_array[row][column] = player_token
    dropping_a_token = false
  else
    row -= 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, Steve, 
Thanks for your answer!
In the top example, can you explain the reasoning for setting row = grid_array.size? 
I'm getting an undefined method for nil:NilClass error in RubyMine - the grid value being accessed is empty.

Comment: Hi, Steve. I built a method that combines a bit of what I had previously and your _hugely_ helpful code that pointed me in the right direction. Reusable for both my human and computer 'players'. I'm writing some error catching for empty array values that bleed over into non-existent rows. Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: Hi, so it should've been `row = grid_array.size -1` the idea being that instead of hard-coding "7" you could get the last line from the size of the array.  Because of my bug (sorry) the method would have attempted to access grid_array[8][column] on the first go-around and grid_array[8] doesn't exist so you would get undefined method [] for nil:NilClass (because `[column]` can't be called on nil)

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to correct this (for posterity) but glad you're making progress!